# How do you assign a value to a key from a parameter into a ActionController::Parameters object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you assign a value to a key from a parameter into a `ActionController::Parameters` object?

What I tried:

```
(byebug) foo_inquiry_params
<ActionController::Parameters {"email"=>"fds@fsdgf.com", "subject"=>"fds", "description"=>"fds"} permitted: true>
(byebug) name_inquiry_params["user_id"] = 5
5
(byebug) foo_inquiry_params
<ActionController::Parameters {"email"=>"fds@fsdgf.com", "subject"=>"fds", "description"=>"fds"} permitted: true>
(byebug)
```

Comment: It's unclear for me what you're asking.

Comment: self.params["user_id"] = 5, nope?

Comment: do you mean assign a value to a key from `params`?

Comment: `foo_inquiry_params` looks like a method. Use something like `params[:foo][:user_id] = 5`.

Comment: yes, I mean assign a value to a key from params

Comment: fyi key doesn't exist in there yet

Answer (score 0):

`ActionController::Parameters` can't be treated like a normal hash, so if you want to call `.merge` on it, you'll have to convert your params to a hash first:

`ActionController::Parameters.new({foo: 'bar'}).to_h.merge({bar: 'baz'})`

A workflow that I find myself using when I have to do this kind of thing is:

```
def update
  attrs_to_update = thing_params.to_h.merge(one_more_attribute: 'some value')
  @thing.update(attrs_to_update)
end

def thing_params
  params.require(:thing).permit(:some_attribute, :another_attribute)
end
```